# grub-mkconfig not detecting any operating systems

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I'm running the following command in a chroot, and it doesn't detect any operating systems (linux and windows on one SSD).

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Here's my `grub.cfg`: http://sprunge.us/ECDEPS

Here's my `fdisk -l`: http://sprunge.us/JfJDdM

Here's my `findmnt`: http://sprunge.us/fj9DQc

Here's `lsblk`: http://sprunge.us/9LUvZT

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have my boot partition mounted when installing linux. Doing the following with /boot mounted fixes it:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/linux-*
```